# Ruby IPAddr: find address mask

Tags: ruby, ip-address

I have an application where I process a lot of IP addresses (analysing Checkpoint firewall rule sets).  At one point I want to check if a particular address object is a /32 or a 'network'.

Currently I am doing it like this:

`next unless ip.inspect.match(/\/255\.255\.255\.255/)`

it works but seems a bit inefficient but I can't see any method that extracts the mask from the address object.

Comment: You can't do this without knowing the mask or having other data of some sort. Is `192.168.1.0` an IP or a network?  It could be part of a /23. Can you give better, more complete examples?

Comment: That's strange, indeed there is no accessor for the netmask. You can make your code a tad more efficient by not doing a `Regexp` match over the entire string: `ip.inspect.end_with?('/255.255.255.255>')`, but that's about all you can do.

Comment: Jorg:  thanks that will certainly be faster than RE invocation!

Comment: Tadman: the point is that the IPAddr class stores the netmask as part of every object but there does not appear to be any obvious way to access it.   In my application I have a mix of networks masks ranging from /32 to /8 with /32s being a special case that I need to check for.

Comment: @tadman: The only way to get access to the netmask seems to be through parsing the output of `IPAddr#inspect`, which is a horrible hack: `inspect` is intended for human-readable debugging output, nothing more. It is *not* meant to be parsed. There is an `IPAddr#mask` method, which sure looks like it were an accessor for the netmask, but it actually does something completely different: it constructs a new ip address from the current one by applying a different mask.

Comment: @JörgWMittag When the Ruby Standard Library hands you lemons, apply monkey patches to get lemonade.

Comment: @tadman: Or get some salt and a bottle of tequila.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some parts of the Ruby core library are sometimes just sketched in, and IPAddr appears to be one of those that is, unfortunately, a little bit incomplete.

Not to worry. You can fix this with a simple monkey-patch:

```
class IPAddr
  def cidr_mask
    case (@family)
    when Socket::AF_INET
      32 - Math.log2((1<<32) - @mask_addr).to_i
    when Socket::AF_INET6
      128 - Math.log2((1<<128) - @mask_addr).to_i
    else
      raise AddressFamilyError, "unsupported address family"
    end
  end
end
```

That should handle IPv4 and IPv6 addresses:

```
IPAddr.new('151.101.65.69').cidr_mask
# => 32

IPAddr.new('151.101.65.69/26').cidr_mask
# => 26

IPAddr.new('151.101.65.69/255.255.255.0').cidr_mask
# => 24

IPAddr.new('2607:f8b0:4006:800::200e').cidr_mask
# => 128

IPAddr.new('2607:f8b0:4006:800::200e/100').cidr_mask
# => 100
```

It's not necessarily the best solution here, but it works.

Answer (score 4):

I'm aware that this is a 3 year old question, but this was the first result on Google for me when I searched it, so I want to provide a new answer.

I was playing around in console today and noticed the the `prefix` method on the `IPAddr` object returns cidr mask as an integer.

So, for example:

```
ip = IPAddr.new("192.168.1.0/24")
ip.prefix 
  # => 24
```

It also turns out that type coercion gives you the integer representation of the address and mask, so you could potentially do the math on the output of `to_i`, `to_json`, `as_json` or `instance_values`.

An example with the network address:

```
ip.to_i 
  # => 3232235776

ip.to_i.to_s(2) 
  # => "11000000101010000000000100000000"
```

And one with the netmask:

```
ip.as_json 
  # => {"family"=>2, "addr"=>3232235776, "mask_addr"=>4294967040}

ip.as_json["mask_addr"].to_s(2) 
  # => 11111111111111111111111100000000

ip.as_json["mask_addr"].to_s(2).count("1")
  # => 24
```